# How to access C++ libraries in Octave coding

Tags: c++, matlab, octave

I have the task to make some scripts compatible to Octave (or create counterparts that run in Octave).

I am trying to handle this matlab part:

```
%ft = fittype( 'a+b*y*x+c*y^2', 'independent', {'x', 'y'}, 'dependent', 'z' );
%
%opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
%opts.Display = 'Off';
%opts.Lower = [0 0 0];
%
%opts.MaxFunEvals = 10000;
%opts.MaxIter = 10000;
%opts.Robust = 'Bisquare';
%opts.StartPoint = [0.12345 0.456789 0.23456];
%[fitresult, gof] = fit( [xData, yData], zData, ft, opts );
%coeffs=coeffvalues(fitresult);
```

There's obviously no direct equivalent to this toolbox from Matlab in Octave.
I can do linear and nonlinear regression, but not robust. So I looked around for alternative ways.

I found that GSL can calculate fittings using the same biweight robust alghorithm.
https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/lls.html?highlight=robust#c.gsl_multifit_robust_alloc
I think there are ways to call GSL libraries form Octave (the forge package gsl does not include the funtions I need).

So my questions:
a) Working on windows, can I make octave use those libraries? (I know it can call C++ functions). And can I include those libraries to give ppl with "just" octave a "package" to make it work together?

b) Any leads on how to go this way?
In the documentation it is only described how to make .oct files (c++ code) that use octave and c++ libraries. But I'd like to stay within octave code (and .m files).

Comment: You probably don’t have an alternative to creating an OCT or MAT file. If you want to call a C++ library you need to code in C++.

Comment: *OCT or MEX file

Comment: just a thought, instead of resorting to c++ you could use the python interface to wrap an octave function calling python libraries (e.g. https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/rlm.html ) under the hood.

Comment: The goal was to create "packages" including research data and evaluation/plotting functions to distribute. When I have to make them install a C++ Parser or Python it was considered "too complicated", so for now the decision was made to only do non-robust fittings in octave.
But I will definitely note down the pythong interface in case this project will be expanded in  a later date. Especially since it is planned to change most of the data handling to python based code anyways.